# Unable to use closure on loop and setInterval

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to print 0 to 9 value after a delay of 10 milliseconds without forming any other named function.

```
function ClosurePrint(){
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    document.writeln(function(y){
                        return y;
                    })(i);
                },10);
            }
        }
        ClosurePrint();
```

Currently, it`s printing:

```
function(y) { return y }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a function `reference` to document.write that will results in printing the `primitive` value of it. You could use the 3rd parameter of `setTimeout` to use it as an argument of passed function.

No need to handle the closure problem here by creating a scope per iteration.

```
function ClosurePrint(){
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    setTimeout(function(i){ 
        document.writeln(i) 
    },1000 * i, i);
 }
}

ClosurePrint();
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fesxbzf7/1/)

I haven't used `document.write` as same as you given in your sample. I have used `console.log`. Press F12 to see your console.

By handling the `closure` problem, you can write it like below by using an `IIEF`,

```
function ClosurePrint(){
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.writeln(i);
      },1000 * i);
    })(i);
 }
}

ClosurePrint();
```

Comment: The task is to implement the above problem using closure. If you can tell me that way, it will be great. Thanks for the help though.